# input type="file" validation for contains file

Tags: jquery

I'm using this html below:

```
<input name="t1" class="imgupload" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Upload">
```

I'm trying to figure out how to have some alert(); show when the input type="file" is empty

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function(e) {
var check = $(".imgupload").val();
    if(check == 'undefined'){
       alert();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example

http://jsfiddle.net/aesmA/

HTML

```
<form>
  <input type="file" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
  var $file = $(this).find("input[type=file]");
  if (!$file.val() || $file.val() == "") {
    alert("File is missing");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$('form#fl').submit(function(e){
    var a = $('input.imgupload').val();
    if(a == '' || a == null){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('hello');
    }
   });
```